# what does "driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://172.16.1.34:80"), capabilities); " mean in appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I am new to appium and want to find out what certain line of basic code mean. can anyone tel me what the below code line indicate?
It will be nice if you mention what this url indicate: "http://172.16.1.34:80" 
specially "80" and if it can be changed which other possible port number can be put.

> driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://172.16.1.34:80"), capabilities);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is

```
remoteAddress - is the address of remotely/locally started Appium server
```

In "http://172.16.1.34:80"

```
172.16.1.34 - IP of appium server
80 - Port on which appium is running
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://172.16.1.34:80"), capabilities);
```

The above line indicates that android driver targeting at at ip address `http://172.16.1.34:80` which appium to run scripts.

**Capabilities :** The capabilities are the configuration for test scrip at which environment you want to run script.